# How to get call stack on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

Is there any way to trace the call stack that fires the beforeunload window event?

It is a big SPA and can not find where is it reloading from.

I tried:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    console.trace('page reloaded');   
})
```

But I only get the anonymous function that calls it.

Comment: So you wish to trace the target which originally triggered the `beforeunload` event? You can't, because the event is only triggered on `window`.

Comment: @BenM Yes that is what I want. The thing is that we have tons of window.location.href and location.reload and so on, and I can not figure out which one is triggering the beforeunload. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: If you have several of those, surely each one is triggering it?